# Is there a native Windows build of Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

I've checked the download page for Memgraph, and I can see that Memgraph Lab exist as native app. The same goes for `mgconsole`.

Is there a native build of `memgraphdb` for Windows? I can see only the Docker one.

[image]

I've also checked the Memgraph Internals docs (https://memgraph.notion.site/Memgraph-Internals-12b69132d67a417898972927d6870bd2) but I couldn't find anything Windows related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Memgraph natively works on Linux, actually Docker/WSL/LimaVM are derived based on the native Linux package.

You will need to use WSL or Docker to run Memgraph.

Memgraph Lab is a standalone app that you can use to connect Memgraph. It  doesn't need to be installed on same computer where is Memgraph database.